# How data flows through internet?

Tags: internet, isp, broadband, web-application

Say i hit `www.google.com` in browser , my question is how data is served from google(or any other website) server to my browser. I raed couple of articles/videos . Based on them here is mine understanding and some inline questions

1. I enter www.google.com in browser
2. Browser resolves google name with IP though DNS server(with the help of my Internet service Provider(ISP))
3. Data travels from my latop to modem in my room
4. Modem send the data to my ISP say comcast
5. Now each ISP is connected to internet exchange physically(through wire) Right ?
6. Google server is also connected to Internet exchange.If yes not sure how ? Similarly if i host my new website through any web hosting service provider(WHSP), then that WHSP must be connected to internet exchange
7. Then router at internet exchange will route the data to google server connected to Internet exchange
8. Google server will process the request and send the response back

Please correct if i am wrong somewhere here ?

Comment: Conceptually you are pretty close.  Actual implementation could be far more complex.

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: This site is for specific questions about computers and home networking related to issues you are actually facing. There are literally tons of resources available that explain how the Internet works. Just not a fit for this site.

Comment: @Guys Shared link does not answer my question. That link mainly tell how browser sends/receives the data from another server but does not explain how data is traveling from `browser  > ISP  >  Internet exchange > Server ISP`  Request you to reopen the question or confirm if my understanding is correct ?